# mod_pagespeed many "Unrecognized Script" messages in the console

Tags: mod-pagespeed

I am running mod_pagespeed (Apache) on my server and it is functioning great, apart from many "info level" messages in the admin console log.  The site is currently scoring 94/89 on GTMetrix and I'm at the point of trying to squeeze that last bit of juice from this wonderful module.

These messages refer to unrecognised scripts that mod_pagespeed was attempting to process.  In most cases they contain json or text/html, i.e.:

`[Wed, 29 Jan 2020 13:17:10 GMT] [Info] [16645] [https://www.example.com/comment/:271] Unrecognized script:'<script type='application/ld+json'></script> 271...295'
[Wed, 29 Jan 2020 13:17:10 GMT] [Info] [16645] [https://www.example.com/comment/:88] Unrecognized script:'<script type='application/ld+json' class='yoast-schema-graph yoast-schema-graph--main'></script> 88...88'
[Wed, 29 Jan 2020 13:13:01 GMT] [Info] [14352] [https://www.example.com/comment/:47] Unrecognized script:'<script type="text/html" id="wpb-modifications"></script> 47...47'
[Wed, 29 Jan 2020 13:13:01 GMT] [Info] [14352] [https://www.example.com/comment/:11] Unrecognized script:'<script type='application/ld+json'></script> 11...33'
[Wed, 29 Jan 2020 13:13:01 GMT] [Info] [14352] [https://www.example.com//:11] Unrecognized script:'<script type='application/ld+json' class='yoast-schema-graph yoast-schema-graph--main'></script> 11...11'`

Does anyone here know of any way to configure Pagespeed to be able to recognise this format?

I've already fixed some issues with unrecognised image links within some tags:

`ModPagespeedUrlValuedAttribute img data-lazy-src image
ModPagespeedUrlValuedAttribute a data-tolb-src image`

And those assets are now being rewritten/compressed.

My main problem is that I don't know how to get Pagespeed to recognise these script tags.

Is there a way?  (*Is it even necessary for these type of script tags?*)

Many thanks in advance.